# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following extension methods in which I am using to do a Contains on LINQ-To-Entities:

```
  public static class Extensions
  {    
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity, TValue>
        (
            this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> selector,
            IEnumerable<TValue> collection
        )
        {
            if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
            if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
            if (!collection.Any())
                return query.Where(t => false);

            ParameterExpression p = selector.Parameters.Single();

            IEnumerable<Expression> equals = collection.Select(value =>
               (Expression)Expression.Equal(selector.Body,
                    Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

            Expression body = equals.Aggregate((accumulate, equal) =>
                Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

            return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, p));
        }

        //Optional - to allow static collection:
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity, TValue>
          (
            this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> selector,
            params TValue[] collection
          )
        {
            return WhereIn(query, selector, (IEnumerable<TValue>)collection);
        }
  }
```

When I call the extenion method to check if a list of ids is in a particular table, it works and I get back the List of ids, like this:

```
List<int> Ids = _context.Persons
                        .WhereIn(x => x.PersonId, PersonIds)
                        .Select(x => x.HeaderId).ToList();
```

When I execute the next statement, it complains that LINQ-To-Entities does not recogonize Contains(int32), but I thought I am not going against the entity anymore, but a collection of ints.

```
predicate = predicate.And(x=> Ids.Contains(x.HeaderId));
```

If I have a comma separated string such as "1,2,3", then the following works:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x=>x.Ids.Contains(x.HeaderId));
```

I am trying to take the List returned and create comma separated list of strings, the problem here is that now when I do `predicate = predicate.And(x=>sb.Contains(x.HeaderId.ToString());`, it complains that it does not like ToString().

I also tried doing:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x=>Extensions.WhereIn(Ids, x.id));, but it can't resolve WhereIn.  It says I must add `<>`, but I am not sure what to add here and how implement it.
```

Comment: code formatted a little bit.

Comment: Where does "predicate" come from? is it an IQueryable?

Comment: @SamBauwens - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Why do you show the WhereIn extension method ? If Ids is really a `List<int>` we don't mind how you get it. The problem seems to come from PredicateBuilder instead (guess you use this)

Comment: @Xaisoft That example is using the Contains method on String, not the Linq Contains extension method.

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 and the EF that does not support Contains.

Comment: Try to use prdicate.And(x => Ids.Any(id => id == x.HeaderId))
 or use 
prdicate.And(x => Ids.FirstOrDefault(id => id == x.HeaderId) != default(int))

Comment: @Xaisoft: You have answered your own question. EF in .NET3.5 does not support `IEnumerable<T>.Contains`. That's all.

Comment: I will update my post

Comment: What's the type of x.PersonId and x.HeaderId??

Comment: They are ints and I can't use ToString on them.

Answer (score 0):

Where is nothing wrong with your **WhereIn**, and you are correct: when you use **Ids**, you are not going against the entity anymore, but a collection of ints.

Problem is when you're using **.And** on predicate: LINQ-To-Entities tries to convert **everything** inside those brackets into Entities methods, and there is no corresponding **Contains** method.

Solution:

Instead of

```
predicate = predicate.And(x=> Ids.Contains(x.HeaderId));
```

use

```
predicate = predicate.And(Contains<XClassName, int>(x.HeaderId));
```

where Contains defined as follows:

```
private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> Contains<TElement, TValue>(Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, List<TValue> values)
    {
        if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }
        if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

        if (!values.Any())
            return e => false;

        var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(@equals.Aggregate(Expression.Or), valueSelector.Parameters.Single());
    }
```

and XClassName is the name of the class of your **x**

Answer (score -1):

You cant use array like that, you need to previsit this lambda in order to expand it to primitives. Alternatively you can change underlying provider so it knows how to generate IN statement , as it doesnt by default.

Didnt find post where one guys actually implement it, will updated once I did.

Basically when you use your extension method it is like

```
x=>arr.Contains(x)
```

So if you try to execute such lambda agains your entityset etc it will throw you exception saying that parameters can only be primitives.

The reason is that underlying provider doesnt know how to convert .Contains method for array as function parameter into sql query. And in order to solve that you have two options

- teach it how to use T[] as parameter and use Contains with this parameter
- update your extension method in order to generate new lamda which will use 'allowed' building blocks, ie expressions using primitive types like int, string, guid etc.

Check this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit with an example. I am a bit confused still.

Answer (score -2):

Replace your:

```
List<int> Ids = _context.Persons
                    .WhereIn(x => x.PersonId, PersonIds)
                    .Select(x => x.HeaderId).ToList();
```

with

```
var Ids = _context.Persons
                    .WhereIn(x => x.PersonId, PersonIds)
                    .Select(x => x.HeaderId).ToList();
```

and then try.